# IE 11, Flexbox, and Absolute Positioning Not Working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

This is how Chrome renders my HTML in Windows 10:

[image: Chrome]

And this is how Internet Explorer 11 renders my HTML in Windows 10:

[image: Internet Explorer 11]

Notice that in Chrome you can see all of the submenu links, but in Internet Explorer 11 you can't. What can I do to make it work in Internet Explorer 11?

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  min-width: 1280px;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.active {
  color: #f00;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu > li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu > li + li {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.submenu-4,
.submenu-5 {
  right: 0;
}

.submenu li {
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.submenu > li + li {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

a:not(.active) + ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Link 1</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-1">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Link 2</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-2">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Link 3</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-3">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="active">Top Level Link 4</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-4">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Link 5</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-5">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you using alll the relevant IE flexbox variant syntaxes - http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @Paulie_D The only thing I'm doing with flexbox is `display: flex;` (and its variants). The HTML is being rendered with the default flexbox settings.

Comment: How does the submenu look if top level link 1 is active?

Comment: That is weird. Everything is working except for the `right:0` value

Comment: @Pangloss It looks fine. I want it so that top level links 1 through 3 show the submenu left aligned (since it fits like that) and top level links 4 and 5 show the submenu right aligned.

Comment: Looks like a bug in IE, use css table or inline block instead I'd say.

Comment: Hi Even with ```right: 0``` is also working on IE11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that IE11 is not recognizing the `right: 0` offset applied to the absolutely-positioned flex container (`.submenu`).

Considering the layout works in Chrome and Firefox, the problem is likely a bug in IE11, which wouldn't be a surprise.

On the popular browser compatibility website [*caniuse.com*](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), IE11 used to have a full green badge for flexbox. That means IE11 provides full support. Recently, however, IE11 was downgraded to pale green, meaning partial support, [*due to a large amount of bugs present*](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Here's a simple workaround:

```
.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;  /* <-- ADD THIS */
}
```

The `flex-direction` property determines the direction in which flex items are laid out. The default setting is `flex-direction: row`. With `row-reverse` (and `column-reverse`) the *main-start* and *main-end* directions are swapped.

This fixes the problem in IE11, without breaking anything in other browsers.

However, it does reverse the order of the links in all browsers.

To address that issue you can reverse the order of the links in the source, or use the [flex `order` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-property) to reverse the order on the screen only:

```
.submenu-4 > li:nth-child(1) { order: 5 ; }
.submenu-4 > li:nth-child(2) { order: 4 ; }
.submenu-4 > li:nth-child(3) { order: 3 ; }
.submenu-4 > li:nth-child(4) { order: 2 ; }
.submenu-4 > li:nth-child(5) { order: 1 ; }
```

Full code (tested in Firefox, Chrome and IE11):

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  min-width: 1280px;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.active {
  color: #f00;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu > li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu > li + li {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;                   /* NEW */
}

.submenu-4,
.submenu-5 {
  right: 0;
}

.submenu li {
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.submenu > li + li {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

a:not(.active) + ul {
  display: none;
}

.submenu-4 > li:nth-child(1) { order: 5 ; }        /* NEW */
.submenu-4 > li:nth-child(2) { order: 4 ; }        /* NEW */
.submenu-4 > li:nth-child(3) { order: 3 ; }        /* NEW */
.submenu-4 > li:nth-child(4) { order: 2 ; }        /* NEW */
.submenu-4 > li:nth-child(5) { order: 1 ; }        /* NEW */
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Link 1</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-1">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Link 2</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-2">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Link 3</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-3">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="active">Top Level Link 4</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-4">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Link 5</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-5">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gad7q1f/)

Comment: I'm seeing this bug also. Surprisingly, it doesn't seem to be discussed in https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Comment: Note that someone reported an issue with IE11 and flexbox at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12500543/ and Microsoft said they won't fix issues with IE11

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm very much in favour of adopting Flexbox and I do in all my recent projects, it doesn't seem to play an important role in your code. With that in mind, you should know that there's an easier and more maintainable fix to this specific problem if you remove `display: flex` and its variants from the CSS and add `white-space: nowrap` to `.submenu`.

This way you won't have to deal with reordering submenu items, which can be a problem if the number of items change.

One day, when IE11 is not a concern anymore, you can go back to your original code.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  min-width: 1280px;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.active {
  color: #f00;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu > li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu > li + li {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  /* removed flexbox */
  white-space: nowrap; /* new */
}

.submenu-4,
.submenu-5 {
  right: 0;
}

.submenu li {
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.submenu > li + li {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

a:not(.active) + ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Link 1</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-1">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Link 2</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-2">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Link 3</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-3">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="active">Top Level Link 4</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-4">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Top Level Link 5</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu-5">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 5 Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rddo2gr4/